# Partial derivative of $f(x, y) = x ^ {x ^ {x ^ {x ^ y}}} + \ln(x)[\tan^{-1} (\tan^{-1}(\tan^ {-1}(\sin(\cos xy)-\ln(x+y)))]$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

If $$f(x, y) = x ^ {x ^ {x ^ {x ^ y}}} + \ln(x)[\tan^{-1} (\tan^{-1}(\tan^ {-1}(\sin(\cos xy)-\ln(x+y)))]$$
Then what are the values of partial derivative $f_x(1,2)$ and $f_x(1,5)?$

I tried my best but couldn't fight with such a difficult calculations involved in finding partial derivative. Is there any short and easy approach to find partial derivative of such a typical function?

Comment: Seems a question for Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: But this was asked in a competitive exam...so there must be some handy calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the first summand, as $x^{g(x,y)}$ has the derivative
$$ x^{g(x,y)}\left(g_x(x,y)\log x + \frac{g(x,y)}x\right)$$
Now note that $\log 1 = 0$, hence the derivative of the first summand at $(1,y)$ is
$$ 1^{g(1,y)} \cdot \frac{g(1,y)}1  = 1 $$
where we used that our $g(1,y) = 1^{1^{1^y}} = 1$.

Same trick for the second summand. It's a product, the first factor is $\log x$, now the derivative of $\log x \cdot h(x,y)$ is
$$ \log x \cdot h_x(x,y) + \frac{h(x,y)}x $$
plugging in $x = 1$ we have
$$ \frac{h(1,y)} 1 $$
So the partial derivative with respect to $x$ at $(1,y)$ of the given function is
$$ f_x(1,y) = 1 + \arctan \arctan \arctan \bigl(\sin(\cos y)- \log (1+y)\bigr) $$